# cant fix ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, file, console

I'm new to coding and was trying to use an image but I kept on getting ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in the console. I've been trying for a while but can't find the solution. Please help.

```
<img src="Untitled-2.jpg" width="800" height="500"> </img>
```

Comment: ``ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`` this means that your file is not present in the same location as that of this HTML file.     PS- Addition information, in HTML5 you don't need to close the ``<img>`` tag. Using ``</img>`` or ``<img src="some--img-link.jpg" />`` are part of **XHTML**

Comment: check the image path again to see if the image file really exists, there could be a typo in the image name, check whether the uploaded image is actually jpg..

Answer (score 0):

Where is your file located?

If its in a different folder, you will have to type out the path from your current directory. For example if its in an images folder it'd be:

`<img src="/images/Untitled-2.jpg" width="800" height="500"> </img>`

Also, are you using the correct case for spelling? file names are case sensitive.